# Why can I not create a core when running a 2nd Apache Solr instance?

Tags: solr

My first instance:

```
sudo bin/solr start -p 8983 -s ../coaps
```

My second instance:

```
sudo bin/solr start -p 8984 -s ../newcoaps
```

Using the python http utility I verified connections:

```
http :8983/solr/
http :8984/solr/
```

I can ping my first one with `:8983/solr/samos/admin/ping/` but I can NOT ping the other one because the core located in `../newcoaps` is not added upon startup.

The `../newcoaps` directory looks like this before I started up Solr:

```
ls -R ../newcoaps/
../newcoaps/:
samos  solr.xml

../newcoaps/samos:
conf  data

../newcoaps/samos/conf:
schema.xml  solrconfig.xml

../newcoaps/samos/data:
```

I copied the files in here directly from my other instance, which is running smoothly. Everything is default except for several fields I defined.

In the web browser, I see that the second instance has no cores, so I tried to add it manually but I get this response:

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: Can't find resource 'synonyms.txt' in classpath or '/opt/solr/newcoaps/samos'
```

What is going on here and why is that file important enough to prevent me from adding this core? What steps can I take to figuring out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema (schema.xml) is referencing the `synonyms.txt` file (in [a SynonymFilter definition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-SynonymFilter)). Remove the filter from the configuration if you're not expanding synonyms, or create an empty file named `synonyms.txt` to allow the core to start up.

As a possible explanation: If you started the first node without a schema.xml present the first time, it might have switched to using the managed schema functionality instead of reading the schema.xml, but when starting the second node with the schema present, it'll try to read and parse it.

Comment: Ahhh. It's been a while since I first setup my first Solr instance, but I think I originally copied most of the conf files from `server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/`. I ended up just copying everything from the first instance instead of only the schema and solrconfig files. I guess the default config just has a lot of extra stuff in it that I don't use, but requires these files to be present. Thank you for you help!